# Is it feasible to install and play games in steam while steam is in Wine (PlayOnLinux)

Tags: 12.10, steam, playonlinux

So I downloaded steam on PlayOnLinux and I installed some random games and they open but I can't do anything with them I can move the mouse around and the menu buttons change, but I can't actually click anything. The games I tried it on were Castle Crashers, Deus Ex: HR, and Super Meat Boy and they all did the same thing. Should I just download the games from PlayOnLinux and then choose to download the steam version or can I actually have them in Steam, and I'm just doing something wrong. Also I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 using PlayOnLinux 4.19 with a GTX 560 and the NVIDIA Experimental Binary Drivers.

I use native Steam on Ubuntu for the games that are available for Linux, but I want to be able to play my other games that aren't available on Linux, and have them all in steam, instead of having them strewn around in PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Why not native steam

Comment: Because the selection of games is lacking. I just recently switched full time to to Ubuntu from Windows, and I wanted to be able to play most if not all of my games from Windows.

Comment: Steam doesn't do magic, actually Steam doesn't do anything to make the games compatible. It's up to the games themselves. In Wine not all Direct X functions are implemented which means not all Windows games work, some do work fine or without major issues some don't run at all not even the installer. The games need to be ported first, then offered through Steam then you can play them on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

i already know a single virtual drive for steam CAN both install and run more than one game. when i installed skyrim POL gave me 2 buttons on the main screen, one labled skyrim(steam) or something and the other just skyrim, which ran the game. the other opened steam, which i used to install and run rift, as well as install final fantasy 7, but i dont think i ever got it running, for lack of trying. i have a feeling it will probably end up being easier to have different POL entries for each game, cause theyre each gonna need their own different tweaks in order for them to run optimially, let alone properly or even at all. granted every system and setup is unique, so ymmv

i know this post is almost a year old, but if its as high as the third result of a google search, i think its worth answering. sorry dont yet know what the ubuntu community protocol on such things. but im running 12.04 so pretty sure this is still valid info for future searches

Answer (score -1):

It would be extremely unplayable and slow if you manage to get a game installed and working. Just install the native Steam under Linux.

Comment: You can confirm that from your own experience? It would be great if you mention that in your answer :)